# MySQL fulltext search doesn't work for specific word

Tags: php, mysql, sql, full-text-search

i have strange problem: MySQL (MySQL-5.1.61 on PHP/5.2.17) fulltext search doesn't work for word "asus". I have product table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS product (
  pid int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  vendor text NOT NULL,
  series text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (pid),
  FULLTEXT KEY search (vendor,series)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

And some values:

```
INSERT INTO product (vendor,series) VALUES ('Apple','iPad');
INSERT INTO product (vendor,series) VALUES ('Asus','Eee Slate');
INSERT INTO product (vendor,series) VALUES ('Asus','Nexus 7');
INSERT INTO product (vendor,series) VALUES ('Sony','Xperia Tablet Z');
```

When i query

```
SELECT * FROM product WHERE MATCH (vendor,series) AGAINST ('Sony');
```

it works fine, but when field is 'Asus' or 'asus' it doesn't work. I already set ft_stopword_file = "" and recreate DB - nothin change. Min length is 4, so i really don't know what's wrong.

Comment: Could it be some bizarre bug? "As" & "Us" are both stop words.

Comment: List of stopwords: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-stopwords.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The search result is empty because the word “Asus” is present in at least 50% of the rows. As such, it is effectively treated as a stopword.

(taken from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html)

Comment: Thanks! You save my day, don't found this line at first reading.

Answer (score 0):

Your search result is empty because of the limitation of your table engine MyISAM.

On the mysql documentation, when a word is present in at least 50% of the rows. It is treated as a stopword and returns no result. To get a result for small tables, use an InnoDB engine.

Link: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-natural-language.html